# springboot convert YAML to only one Map

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

this is my yaml config

```
a:
  b1: '1'
  b2: '2'
  b3:
    c1: '3'
  b4:
    c2: '4'
```

how can i do to get a javaBean

```
class JavaBean{
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

and when i get this bean ,this map value is like

```
{"a.b1":"1","a.b2","2","a.b3.c1","3","a.b4.c2":"4"}
```

Comment: If the whole yaml file is converted to a `Map<String, String>`, the result is pretty reasonable. What do you expect?  
If you want to have everything below `a:` to be part of the map, you can us `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="a")` with your configuration, but the third level will still contain `b3.c1` and `b4.c2`, because you map a multiple level structure into just a key-value structure.

Comment: @RainerJung, `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation for read the properties file and not for yaml file. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Shakthifuture [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding)

Comment: i  want to get a map which key startwith 'a',i try use @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="a"),but why the map is empty

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on having a **flat** map and not a hierarchical one, Configuration Properties won't help with that since it knows how to handle hierarchical data. Your best bet would be to use a library similar to [json-flattener](https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener#:%7E:text=json-flattener-,A%20Java%20utility%20is%20used%20to%20FLATTEN%20nested%20JSON%20objects,more%20to%20UNFLATTEN%20it%20back.)

You'll need to read the Yaml file as a json and then export it as a a bean

Comment: He want yaml file to map. Not with json file. Read the question again.

Comment: Yaml and json are compatible so when you read a yaml file you effectively get a json object in code. It's just syntactic sugar. I wrote that he will need to read the Yaml file as a json, it's one line of code that can easily be found in SO